# Check All and Check None for WPF & C#

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, revit-api

I'd like to add a Check All and a Check None button for the form below. I can only find examples where the checkboxes are in a data grid or a list box. However, these checkboxes are not set up either way, they are just separate checkboxes:

```xml
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Client Name:"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbClient" Grid.Column="1" Height="25"/>
    <Label Content="Number of floors:" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbFloors" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="25"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Select sheet groups to delete:"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="3">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button x:Name="btnAll" Width="90" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="25"        Content="Chcek All" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btnAll_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNone" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="Check None" Width="90" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btnNone_Click" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>        
    <CheckBox x:Name="chbViews" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Delete unused views" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>        
    <CheckBox x:Name="chbSchedules" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="Delete unused schedules"/>        
    <CheckBox x:Name="chbSchedRename" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="Rename Schedules"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chbCode" Grid.Row="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Clean plan code" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chbGroups" Grid.Row="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="Clean sheet names" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button x:Name="btnOK" Width="90" Height="25" Margin="0,0,5,0" Content="OK" Click="btnOK_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Width="90" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="Cancel" Height="25" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
```

I haven't tried anything yet because I haven't found any relevant examples.

Comment: The traditional way to do this is with a 3-state checkbox (on, off, gray). Create an array of the checkboxes you care about and a method that checks the array. If all are on, check the extra chkbx, if all are off, unchecked it. Otherwise set it gray. Wire things up so that it runs whenever any of the checkboxes changes state. Wire the extra checkbox up so that when it changes state, all of the other checkboxes are set to the state dictated by the master chkbx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the binding for your ListBox in your code. Create ViewModel for each item in your list, then bind the Itemsouce of your ListBox to the list and bind the CheckBox and TextBlock in the teamplate to the property of each item accordingly.
Something like this

```
public class ItemViewModel: INotifyProerptyChanged
{
    public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
}
public class YourMainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public OservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items {get; set;}
}
```

then the .xaml binding

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="3" ItemSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

then it should work fine.

```
public void Update(bool isSelected)
{
    foreach(var item in Items)
    {
        item.IsSelected = isSeletected;
    }
}
```